# Purchase song on iTunes using iTunes credit

Tags: itunes-store

How to purchase a song/album using iTunes store credit? I tried to purchase a song but iTunes Store is asking my credit card while in fact I just redeemed a $15 gift card. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an itunes gift card, it could be asking for your information just to verify that you live in the country you live in. ITunes will always use any remaining iTunes credit before charging a credit card. If all fails, contact Apple for a refund.

Answer (score 0):

The specific way to redeem depends on how you obtained your gift card, whether it's digital or physical, and which device you want to redeem the gift card through. From [Apple's guide](https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT201209#itunes) ("iTunes on Mac or PC" section):

> 1. Depending on where you want to redeem your code, open iTunes, the Mac App Store, or iBooks. (Make sure that you have the latest version of iTunes.)
> 2. From the menu bar, click Store > Sign In to sign in using your Apple ID, if you're not already signed in. Learn how to turn on menus
>      in Windows 7 and 8.
> 3. Click iTunes Store in iTunes, Featured in the Mac App Store, or iBooks Store in iBooks.
> 4. Under the Quick Links section on the right-hand side, click Redeem.
> 5. Enter your gift or content code, then press Return. If you have an iTunes Gift Card, use the 16-digit code on the back of the card that
>      begins with X. In some countries, you can redeem gift cards using your
>      built-in camera.
> 6. If you redeemed a content code, your content, app, or book will automatically begin downloading. After you redeem a gift card code,
>      your iTunes account balance will update. You might need to sign out
>      and back in for your balance to appear. You can check your balance at
>      any time in your account information.
>
> When you redeem a gift card, the amount of the card is credited to
>   your iTunes Store, App Store, iBooks Store, or Mac App Store accounts.
>   Each time you purchase content, iTunes will deduct funds from the
>   credit until it's gone.